# map_server segfaults

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been having an issue with the "rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml" command. I have ros kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 running on a Jetson Tx2. Every time I run the command, the console tells me there has been a “segmentation fault (core dumped).” Here is the link to page with the map.yaml file: https://github.com/mit-racecar/racecar/tree/master/racecar/maps. Is there something wrong with the formatting of the yaml files or is it something else? Also, if I have to build map_server from source, what command would I use to do so.

Thank you,
Michael Chen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303002/map_server-segfaults/) by [Michael Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37427/michael-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-09-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-11**:
I tried to look into that and could actually reproduce the problem. But updating all debian packages fixed it. I'm not sure what the problem has been, I'm assuming some problem with dependencies, but cannot pinpoint it. Maybe @David Lu has some more insights?

Please report if upgrade don't fix it

**Comment by [Michael Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37427/michael-chen/) on 2018-09-11**:
Thanks for the insight! How would I update the debian package? I am unfamiliar with some of this.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-11**:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

**Comment by [Michael Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37427/michael-chen/) on 2018-09-11**:
It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to have been a dependency issue and can be resolved by updating the respective debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-12**:
It could well be that this was caused by the same (presumed) ABI incompatibility that lead to #q303093 being posted.